# Problemas con lentitud de base de datos al realizar consultas con EF desde MVC.NET C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc, entity-framework

Buenas Tardes Comunidad,

Tengo un problema ya que después de realizar consultas a la base de datos desde varios usuarios se me esta volviendo lenta y llega al punto de no poder realizar ninguna consulta. Las consultas las estoy realizando desde entityFramework.

Realicé un SP_WHO y encontré un montón de cadenas de conexión después de realizar un kill ya me volvió el sistema a trabajar bien. Mi consulta es saber si se puede eliminar esas cadenas desde Entity ya que todas se encuentran en status sleeping.

Hice una función global para realizar un dispose pero sigue almacenando procesos.

Me pueden ayudar por favor, gracias.

Comment: Estas ocupando inyección de dependencia para el context??

Comment: Lo único que hago es al iniciar sesión obtengo la cadena de conexión y se la agrego a una estacia del entity. y hago los mantenimiento necesarios y posterior realizo el dispose.

Comment: Lo que pasa es hay varias formas de consultar una base de datos en asp mvc. Entonces lo mejor es que edites tu pregunta y pongas un ejemplo de como lo haces, obviamente la consulta no es relevante, lo que importa es saber el mecanismo de instanciación que haces para realizar dicha consulta